# Convert Casbah findOne to Map

Tags: scala, casbah

```
 val db = mongoClient("test") 
 val coll = db("test")
 val q  = MongoDBObject("id" -> 100) 
 val result= coll.findOne(q)
```

How can I convert `result` to a map of key --> value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

result of findOne is an Option[Map[String, AnyRef]] because MongoDBObject is a Map.
A Map is already a collection of pairs.
To print them, simply:

```
for {
   r <- result
   (key,value) <- r
}
yield println(key + " " + value.toString)
```

or

```
result.map(_.map({case (k,v) => println(k + " " + v)}))
```

To serialize mongo result, try `com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize`, like

```
com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(result.get)
```

Comment: So I stored `k -> v` into a mutable Map. If I have `currency-> [ { "id" : 1.0} , { "id" : 2.0}]`, how would I get `List(1.0, 2.0)`

Comment: If you want to get values of key "id" from a collection of maps, it should be: 
`result.flatMap(_.get("id"))`

Comment: Try `com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize`